# Most efficient "ignore if exists" in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Once per day, I am hitting an API to get the 50 most recent posts from a forum. I'm storing that information in a database, one row per post, storing Author, Title, and PostID.

If there are less than 50 posts in a day, then there will be duplicate data, the same posts would appear twice or more. I want to avoid this. I want to say "if PostID already exists in the database, just skip inserting that record."

I can easily do this by first fetching a list of all PostIDs and saving it as an array in my program, then making sure the PostID isn't in that array before inserting; but that seems dumb and sloppy. Surely there must be a way to do it in the database itself.

I've read up a little, and `INSERT OR REPLACE` works, but also seems like it's not the 'correct' solution. It would also pose a problem if I wanted to alter a field in the row -- hitting the API again would reset all fields to initial values.

What's the smart way to do this?

Comment: Is there a way in API to fetch articles by ID ?

Comment: Can we pass the ID /Date of latest article that we have, and fetch the articles that are newer than that. Instead of fetching 50 articles?
This would save you some bandwidth as well.

Comment: `INSERT OR REPLACE works, but also seems like it's not the 'correct' solution` ... does it work? Then it **is** the "correct" solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want `INSERT OR IGNORE`. It will silently skip all duplicate inserted rows, and won't modify the pre-existing ones.

See [the `ON CONFLICT` clause documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) for details.